# Codeigniter 3 - callback function that is called only if another field is selected

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have form with one `select` with `option values` 0 and 1, and one `input` that should be validated only if `select` is set to 1.

How i can make callback function on input field that is called only if selected value is 1.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validate(value) {
  if (value == 1) {
    $("#my_txt").val(value);
  } else {
    $("#my_txt").val('');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="return validate(this.value)" id="my_select">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="" id="my_txt">
```

Comment: If you only want to execute the code when the value is 1 then remove the else part from the condition. and change the code inside the if condition as you want.

Comment: hi, i need validation on form in controller using php not jquery

Answer (score 0):

try this:

function checkIT()
{

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('my_select', 'my select', 'callback_username_check');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
            $this->load->view('myform');
    }
    else
    {
            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
    }
}
public function username_check($str)
{
    if ($str == '1')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The select field can not be 0');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for it, first need to check value of select then validate input and call callback function for input

```
// if selected value is set to 1 do validation
if ($this->input->post('select_value') == 1) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputname', '', 'trim|required|xss_clean|greater_than_equal_to[0]|callback_myfcallbackfunction');
}
```